# PHP extension "Zend Optimizer|Zend Guard Loader" is not loaded in OVH Server

Tags: php, zend-framework

I downloaded a html template from Templatemonster.com and I uploaded it on OVH server but it says:

> PHP extension "Zend Optimizer|Zend Guard Loader" is not loaded.
>   Please verify your server configuration. Make sure that extension "Zend Optimizer|Zend Guard Loader" is enabled.

Comment: This isn't a programming question and probably better suited on one of the administrator sites, like Server Fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the "Zend Optimizer" extension to be installed on your server.  If you have a shared hosting account, ask your web host to install it for you.  It's very easy and doesn't cost anything - full details here:

http://www.zend.com/topics/Zend-Optimizer-User-Guide-v330-new.pdf